# Send search query to Google and extract the listed websites in java without using any 3rd party library

Tags: java

Send search query to Google and extract the listed websites in java without using any 3rd party library

Code I've tried to pull search results

```
public void getSearchPages() {
    URL url;
    StringBuilder parsedContentFromUrl = new StringBuilder();
    String urlString="https://www.google.com.au/search?q=online title search&num=2";

    if(urlString.contains(" ")) {
        urlString = urlString.replace(" ", "%20");
    }

    url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    uc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");
    uc.connect();
    uc.getInputStream();
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(uc.getInputStream());
    int ch;
    while ((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
      parsedContentFromUrl.append((char) ch);
    }
    System.out.println(parsedContentFromUrl);
}
```

I am able to get webpage content but how to extract all the websites listed without using any 3rd party libraries

Comment: You could possibly use regex to find the expected string.

Comment: Thanks. I am having a file which has 5 matches but my regex just display first match

Comment: String regexString = "a href=\"\\/url\\?q=(.*?)&amp;sa=";
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexString,Pattern.MULTILINE);
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(webContent);
  if (matcher.find())
  {
      System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
  }